# unity3d sqlite error insufficient parameters supplied to the command

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, authentication, field

i want to create login with sqlite in unity. But when i click on the login button, i get sqlite exception: `sqlite error`.
Can you help me to fix that?

```
public void login(){
    var sql_login = "SELECT username,password FROM my_users WHERE username = @login_username AND password = @login_password;";
    SqliteCommand createCommand = new SqliteCommand (sql_login, dbCon);
    using (var cmd =  dbCon.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = sql_login;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_username",login_username.text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_password",login_password.text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqliteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

        while(dr.Read()){
            count++;
        }

        if(count == 1){
            Application.LoadLevel("Succes");
        }

        if(count > 1){
            print("Duplicate");
        }

        if(count < 1){
            print("Not Found");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using two command objects?

Comment: I dont know...i just want to run the query in var sql_login...when the condition query is found i want to go for Application.LoadLevel("succes")...please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two commands objects; you set the parameters in one, but read from the other.

Just use a single one:

```
using (var cmd = dbCon.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = sql_login;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_username", login_username.text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_password", login_password.text);
    SqliteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ...
```

Comment: thank you for the script ... now all goes normal ... thanks a lot